# Issue on binding jQuery UI Slider with Checkbox Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to check and uncheck some checkboxes on jQuery ui slider `stop()` using the following code. But this looks like is not adding any event to the check boxes! As you can see the check boxes are re-acting against direct check in out by logging on console but doing nothing when slider change. Why is this happening and how I can fix this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 50,
    max: 54,
    values: [50, 54],
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var selected = [];
      $('input:checkbox[name=temple]').prop("checked", false);
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

      for (var i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++) {
        selected.push(i);
      }
      $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
        $("input:checkbox[name=temple][value=" + value + "]").prop("checked", true);
      })

    }
  });
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});

$('input:checkbox[name=temple]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('Checked');
  } else {
    console.log('Un Checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="js-lwidths">


  <input type="checkbox" name="temple" value="50">50<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="temple" value="51">51<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="temple" value="52">52<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="temple" value="53">53<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="temple" value="54">54<br>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe prop("checked", {value}) does not fir the change event, you will need to add trigger('change') as well.

Comment: Hi gmfm thanks for comment but can you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe prop("checked", {value}) does not fire the change event, you will need to add trigger('change') as well

try:

```
$(function() {
          $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 50,
            max: 54,
            values: [50, 54],
            stop: function(event, ui) {
              var selected = [];
              $('input:checkbox[name=temple]').prop("checked", false);
              $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

              for (var i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++) {
                selected.push(i);
              }
              $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
                $("input:checkbox[name=temple][value=" + value + "]").prop("checked", true);
                $("input:checkbox[name=temple][value=" + value + "]").trigger("change");
              })

            }
          });
          $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
            " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

        $('input:checkbox[name=temple]').on('change', function() {
          if ($(this).prop("checked")){
            console.log('Checked');
          } else {
            console.log('Un Checked');
          }
        });
});
```